# Generate color palette from an image for FFmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, gif, color-palette

I want to generate color palette from an image but FFmpeg allows to generate palettes only from videos. The only Bash tool I know that can generate color palettes from images is ImageMagick, but it generates palettes in a `*.txt` and I need a `*.png` palette.

Is there a bash tool to generate palettes with fine control? Or maybe there is a way to do it in FFmpeg?

P.S. I need that palette to create GIF in FFmpeg.

Comment: *FFmpeg allows to generate palettes only from videos* --> not at all. For ffmpeg, an image is a video with 1 frame.

Comment: @Mulvya, you are right. I just renamed **.png** to **.mov** and was able to generate the palette.

Comment: You don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you have to do some extra work as most software has limits. For example you say "but it generates palettes in a *.txt and I need a *.png palette. " well you are half way there. Use the text output to create a png image. There are a few posts on the imagemagick forum about it and here is one: http://wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25478

```
list=`convert beach.jpg +dither -colors 5 -unique-colors txt:- | tail -n +2 | sed -n 's/^.*\#.* \(.*\).*$/xc\:\1/p'`
convert -size 50x50 $list -append palette.png
```

There was a thread about colour pallets from different software giving different results which is something to beware of.

Comment: Not sure what all the text and `sed` are for? Why not just `convert beach.jpg +dither -colors 5 -unique-colors palette.gif`?

Comment: I do not use Linux so it is all gibberish to me @Mark Setchell ! I think the code writes to a text file in memory then reads the text file to format the data into something Imagemagick can use. There was a better thread on the Imagemagick site with more information and ideas but I could not find it. If the OP had searched the web as well as here there are other threads with similar examples to yours.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate palette from PNG with ffmpeg. Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i target.png -vf palettegen palette.png
```